# Read value from Text Field in Xamarin UI test REPL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

I am working on automation of our `cross-platform` app in Visual Studio 2013 with Xamarin. And I am currently struggling to read the value from Text Field on a page. Is there a method that can be used to do this?

Example of the element attributes from `REPL`:

```
Id => "app_url",
Label => "ApplicationUrlEntryField",
Text => "https://myurladdress.com",
Class => "android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView",
Enabled => true
```

Now, i need the Text value => https://myurladdress.com

Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

Actually solve it:

`app.Query(x => x.Marked("ApplicationUrlEntryField").Invoke("getText"));` - get the Value of a text by its id

Comment: After you have started REPL, you can run the [`tree` command](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/repl/#Discovering_Views_With_the_tree_Command). This will display the list of views that are visible on the screen and also the `text` properties hereof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Text` Property from `app.Query` to retrieve the value.

I also like to include a null-check and return `string.Empty` if for some reason `app.Query` fails.

```cs
string GetApplicationUrlEntryFieldText()
{
    System.Func<Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery, Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery> applicationUrlEntryField = x => x.Marked("ApplicationUrlEntryField");

    app.WaitForElement(applicationUrlEntryField);

    var applicationUrlEntryFieldQuery = app.Query(applicationUrlEntryField);

    return applicationUrlEntryFieldQuery?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This helped me a lot.